# react-konva Text - onClick does not work on mobile

Tags: reactjs, mobile, konvajs

I'm using react-konva in my webapp and on the desktop browser it works perfectly, but on the mobile browser the `onClick` does not work.

```js
<Text
    key={index}
    index={index}
    x={position[0]}
    y={position[1]}
    fontSize={unit}
    width={unit}
    text={mark}
    fill={fill}
    fontFamily={'Helvetica'}
    align={'center'}
    onClick={ (event) => {
      alert("Some text...")
    }}
/>
```

Is there a way to get this to work on mobile or do I need to find a replacement for react-konva text?

Comment: RTFM [Konva mobile events](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/events/Mobile_Events.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use a special mobile event: `onTap`.

https://konvajs.github.io/docs/events/Mobile_Events.html

So in your case just use `onClick` and `onTap` together.

```
<Text
   {...attrs}
   onClick={this.handleClick}
   onTap={this.handleClick}
/>
```